# Flutter Laravel Echo

Tags: laravel, flutter, pusher

I'm new in Flutter Dev and I want to connect  pusher using laravel app to my Flutter app.When subscribing to the event,Flutter binds the Event.I realised that the app is not being able to connect.I receive the http exception ,I don't know exactly which kind of exception.

```
PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
  host: 'http://www.api.dassam.net',
  port: 80,
  encrypted: false,
  activityTimeout: 1200000
);

FlutterPusher pusher =
    FlutterPusher('XXXXXX', options, enableLogging: true,
        onConnectionStateChange: (ConnectionStateChange x) async {
     print(x.currentState);
},onError: (ConnectionError y)=>{
  print(y.exception)
});

Echo echo = new Echo({
  'broadcaster': 'pusher',
  'client': pusher,
  "useTLS": false,
});

echo.channel('public').listen('EssaiEvent', (e) {
  print('BIEN REUSSI
});
```

Comment: Can you share the full HTTP exception you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.I change the host "http://dassam.net" to pusher wshost and it's working.

```
    PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
    host: 'ws-ap2.pusher.com',
    port: 80,
    encrypted: false,
    cluster: "ap2",
    activityTimeout: 120000);

FlutterPusher pusher = FlutterPusher("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", options,
    enableLogging: true,
    onConnectionStateChange: (ConnectionStateChange x) async {
      print(x.currentState);
      
    },
    onError: (ConnectionError y) => {print(y.message)});

Echo echo = new Echo({
  'broadcaster': 'pusher',
  'client': pusher,
});

echo.channel('public').listen('EssaiEvent', (e) {
  print(
      'BIEN REUSSI')
});
```